# i want to enable gridview delete when i right click on grid view.how it is possible in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having gridview and it populated with data. want to enable delete button on right click event of mouse.How it is possible?please help me?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.GridView.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.GridView_MouseDown);


private void GridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
       //code to enable a button
    }
}
```